# "chef-client -j" is not running as expected

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying to bootstrap a node on its own and run the `getting-started` recipe on first boot. Everything seems to work fine except that the actual recipe is never run.

Here is my script which is triggered by `rc.local`:

```
#!/bin/bash

wget http://<some_IP_Address>/chef-11.6.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm -P /var/tmp/
rpm -ivh /var/tmp/chef-11.6.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
mkdir -p /etc/chef
cd /etc/chef
wget http://<some_IP_Address>/chef-validator.pem
mv chef-validator.pem validation.pem

cat > client.rb << EOL
log_level        :auto
log_location     STDOUT
chef_server_url  "MY_CHEF_SERVER_FQDN"
validation_client_name "chef-validator"
EOL

cat > /etc/chef/firstboot.json << EOL
{"run_list": ["recipe[getting-started]"]}
EOL

chef-client -j /etc/chef/firstboot.json
```

Once the node is booted up, I see that the node gets registered with the chef server however the `getting-started` recipe which was specified in `firstboot.json` along with `chef-client -j` on the last line of my script does not get triggered.

It acts like only `chef-client` is being triggered and not `chef-client -j /etc/chef/firstboot.json`

If I look at my workstation, I see that this recipe is added to the node's run_list as well, just that it is not yet executed.

Here is the command output from my chef workstation for the node which was bootstrapped:

```
$ knife node show node_name.domain.com --run-list
node_name.domain.com:
  run_list: recipe[getting-started]
```

**QUESTION:**
Could you tell me what I could be missing here? why chef-client is not able to run whatever mentioned in `firstboot.json`.

**UPDATE:**
If I run `chef-client -j /etc/chef/firstboot.json` manually, then it does the job. So it seems like something is wrong with the `rc.local` invoke. It is running only `chef-client` even if I have mentioned `chef-client -j /etc/chef/firstboot.json`

Thanks.

Comment: Does it have enough permissions to do things stated in _getting-started_ recipe?

Comment: I think so. If I run the same script manually, the recipe gets executed fine. Should I be looking any specific permission with respect to make it run via `rc.local`? Also, I am thinking of using `cloudinit` as a alternative. But this problem should not be so difficult to crack. I guess I am missing something obvious. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "getting-started" recipe is supposed to create "chef-getting-started.txt" under user's home directory. It indeed was creating that file under "/".

But anyway, It validates my thinking around how to bootstrap an instance from autoscalling perspective.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
cat > /etc/chef/firstboot.json << EOL
{"run_list": ["recipe[getting-started]"]}
EOL

chef-client -j /etc/chef/firstboot.json
```

in your script, try:

```
chef-client -o 'getting-started'
```

Comment: Thanks. But It still doesn't run the recipe. It does register itself with chef server as if I had run just `chef-client`. But the `getting-started` recipe does not run. Again, if I run it manually, it works fine. I am thinking this has something to do with the `rc.local` because mine as well as your approach works just fine when I run my script manually. Thanks for your time.